# Any way to force installing Mojave on a Catalina compatible system?

Tags: macos, mojave, imac, catalina

I had an external Mojave boot drive but the drive crashed and both Disk Utility's Restore and disk image mounter say the volume image I made a week ago is bad and can't be used despite having verified and mounted it immediately after creation. I badly need to get Mojave back so I can use my Winclone 7 license to restore the Windows boot partition that was on the internal drive I had upgraded to a higher capacity drive. I can't afford Winclone8 right now.

Comment: Can you [download Mojave from the App store](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210190), then [copy installer to a flash drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372). Boot from flash drive and install Mojave.

Comment: DavidAnderson - Repost your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. It worked perfectly!

Comment: I did not post an answer since your question really is a duplicate of the question [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos). If you want to give reputation points, then you can do so to both the question and accepted answer. Your question will probably be flagged as a duplicate and closed. Anyway, thanks for the thought!

Answer (score -2):

you can use a 8gb USB and download mojove from the App Store.  DL it and before it ask u to install just quit and go the the app folder where it will be.  Right click on it and go to contents then scroll down to somethingMEDIA and if you look up "install mojove on usb using sudo" you will find the directions from there.  Then restart and hold down the option key and you will be able to reboot from that disk.  Before u put anything on the USB make sure u go to disk utility and erase it w/ macOS extended journaled and make it a master bootable drive